# After Star Trek: The Next Generation, can I skip to Voyager without watching Deep Space Nine and not get spoiled?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-ds9

I'm almost done watching the sixth season of Star Trek: The Next Generation, so I'm starting to look at what to watch next. After reading a little bit about Star Trek: Deep Space Nine and Star Trek: Voyager, it's clear to me that Voyager would be fit my current mood.

Would watching Voyager before Deep Space Nine spoil any event of importance?

Comment: However: Perhaps you should reconsider watching DS9 first. Of the two, it is by far the better in overall quality.

Comment: I have a confession: I actually much prefer Voyager to DS9. Let the public shaming begin.

Comment: DS9 is great... except for all the Bajoran-related episodes.

Comment: Clearly, casting Patrick Stewart as the Enterprise-D captain has ruined us all for lesser actors.

Comment: @Blazemonger Are you forgetting about The Shatner?!

Comment: DS9 defeats the whole purpose of ST; there is no exploring. It's largely a cantina stop with way too many episodes devoted to Ferengi shiftiness.

Comment: One scene of S01E01 of VOY makes _more_ sense if you've watched some of DS9 and know the characters, but you won't loose anything if you don't. It's a bit of an Easter egg - nice but not a major plot point.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

There are two ways to approach this question; from the aspect of watching *Voyager* and from the aspect of watching *DS9*.

In the first aspect, you should be able to jump right into *Voyager*.

*Voyager* debuted only a season after *TNG* ended, and the first couple of seasons of *DS9* didn't introduce any major story-lines or continuity that would affect the *Voyager* universe. However, while you should already be aware of the Maquis from watching *TNG*, the Maquis were actually introduced on *DS9* before *TNG* concluded.

Additionally, with the exception of the first episode and some passing mentions in later seasons, *Voyager* has no connection to the rest of the Universe by design. You're supposed to take *Voyager* by itself.

With all that said, *Voyager* is still part of canon and takes place roughly at the same time the events of *DS9* take place. Especially later on in *Voyager*, some allusions and references might make more sense with some knowledge of what's occurred in *DS9*, but it's not necessary at all to understand what's going on in *Voyager*.

If anything, you might want to watch *Star Trek: First Contact* at some point in the first few seasons of *Voyager*. You might also want to watch *Star Trek Generations* so you're not lost on some background info in *Star Trek: First Contact*, but it's not that great a film.

With regards to the second aspect—watching *DS9* unspoiled—those same passing mentions might spoil some of the plot lines of *DS9* (and the Star Trek movies *Generations*-onward, for that matter).

Ideally, you should follow the intended chronology to avoid any chance of spoiling either series. If you wanted to follow chronology, the timeline is roughly:

1. TNG Season 6 starts
2. TNG episode, "Chain of Command"
3. DS9 Season 1 starts halfway through TNG season 6
4. TNG Season 7 and DS9 season 2 begin
5. TNG Ends
6. DS9 Season 3 starts
7. DS9 episode, "Meridian"
8. *Star Trek Generations*, halfway through DS9 season 3
9. DS9 episode, "Past Tense"
10. Star Trek Voyager Season 1 starts halfway through DS9 season 3
11. DS9 season 4 and Voyager season 2 begin
12. DS9 season 5 and Voyager season 3 begin
13. DS9 episode, "Things Past" and Voyager episode, "Warlord"
14. *Star Trek: First Contact*, halfway through DS9 season 5 and Voyager season 3
15. DS9 season 6 and Voyager season 4 begin
16. DS9 season 7 and Voyager season 5 begin
17. DS9 episode, "Covenant" and Voyager episode, "Thirty Days"
18. *Star Trek: Insurrection*, halfway through DS9 season 7 and Voyager season 5
19. DS9 ends
20. Voyager seasons 6 and 7
21. Voyager ends
22. *Star Trek: Nemesis*

Comment: Could you be a little more specific than "first few seasons of Voyager"? After season 3? After season 4?

Comment: @Borror0 one step ahead of you, I added a chronology. Before the end of season 3.

Comment: It's a great answer, but I think it's should emphasize that watching Voyager first WILL spoil several important plot points for DS9. The answer mentions it, but it gets a little lost.

Answer (score 21):

> The conclusion of the Maquis story is in DS9 with acknowledgement of the outcome by the Maquis crewmen of Voyager eventually (once Voyager is able to communicate, however infrequently, with the Alpha quandrant).  So you'll know the eventual outcome of the Maquis faction, but IMHO, it doesn't spoil the DS9 episodes about the Maquis in any significant way.

There are only a couple of potentially significant events in Federation history during DS9, but Voyager is so far out and out of touch, they are largely unaware until long after the fact and those events get largely superficial attention on Voyager (if at all).

To sum up: no, I don't think watching ST:VOY will spoil watching ST:DS9.

Comment: I'm not sure how the spoilered text spoils anything itself. Stating "situation A gets resolved in show x and is also mentioned in show y" in no way spoils what the resolution actually is. You did a nice job of _not_ spoiling anything.

Answer (score 11):

I skipped DS9 and went to Voyager.  So far the only overlap I've seen is the Maquis, but really they aren't important in Voyager - it's more or less a subplot, something to give the maquis characters an edge.  So you don't really need back-story on them to enjoy either series.

Answer (score 1):

I had watched Star Trek: Voyager before DS9, and by the time I got to the parts in DS9 which can relate to Voyager, I hadn't really thought of them. Anyway, as you'll see, the Maquis aren't the headline story of the series! Voyager used to be my favorite Star Trek series by far, but now it's neck and neck with DS9. I think you'll appreciate both of them very much! The 90's had the best of Star Trek in my opinion!

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Deep Space Nine basically stands out that the events, the characters and the story-arc are all totally (Not related) to either TNG nor VOY, though there are some few episodes in DS9 where there are references to TNG, some guest appearances besides there are two TNG crew that became an important part of DS9, Miles O'Brien and Worf but other than that, DS9 is not connected to TNG and esp not Voyager. Have your fun and pick the series you'd like to watch.

Answer (score 0):

You could always watch Star Trek in the order that it aired.

DS9 began in TNG's sixth season, so you could watch a combination of TNG and DS9 episodes. Once you've finished watching TNG and the first two series of DS9, it would make sense to watch watch Generations, followed by the first series of Voyager and DS9 series 3 (at the same time).